# Existe alguma proteção dos arquivos gerados com pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, administração-postgresql

Há proteção de arquivos gerados pelo pg_dump?

Qualquer um que tem acesso a esse arquivo, pode restaurá-lo em qualquer outro banco de dados com o pg_restore?

Existe alguma proteção nesse arquivo, algum tipo de senha ou algo parecido?

Answer (score 3):

Infelizmente não há nada nativo no `postgresql` para tal finalidade, o que você pode fazer para "melhorar" a segurança de seus arquivos, é usar um programa externo para encriptá-los, exemplo:

```
pg_dump -U postgres ... | encrypt  > meu-arquivo.sql.dump
```

Boa sorte

Comment: Entendi, Obrigado.